# How to test mechanics

Tags: dota-2

How can I test certain mechanics (for example whether Manta Style gets you out of Treant Protector's ultimate).

Currently what I do is host a game, get a friend to play the other side, set to appropriate levels via cheats, and then test. This though always requires 2 players involved.

How do I do it solo? I tried for example "-spawnhero Treant Protector", but either he wasn't spawned, or I couldn't find him, so that was useless to me.

I know there has to be a way, since the DotaCinema MythBusters does similar tests, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those commands works in Test Client and that too only in Test Mode

You need to install dota2 client first and start that version and then you create a lobby game and may or may not choose any friends to play with you since you can spawn friend/enemy heros using commands.

But for those commands to work, you need to check "Cheat Enabled" options in the seetttings before you start the game

Once you do that you can try all that stuff

Example,

-createhero npc_dota_hero_clinkz -- this will create bone clinkz as ally

-createhero npc_dota_hero_lina **enemy** -- this will create lina as enemy

Note that they spawn near to you

Here is the complete [list of commands](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Cheat_commands) and actual names/codes of items and heros

Comment: Nice, that works just as I wanted.

Comment: afaik they spawn under your mouse cursor.